# How to log Insert query in Android with ContentProvider?

Tags: android, sqlite

I've been looking for answer to this question, but I couldn't find any.

I am using content provider to insert values to my database. I want to use LogCat to log insert queries.

My code:

```
    public long addSomething(something som)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(something.KEY_NAME, som.get_name() );
    long something_id = db.insert(something.TABLE,null,values);
    Log.e("INSERT QUERY","What should I put here to get that query??");
    return something_id;
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The actual INSERT statement is constructed internally, and is not made available to the caller.

The best you can do is to log all the parameters to `insert()` (use [toString()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/ContentValues.html#toString()) for the `ContentValues`).